# what is the difference between QString::sprintf and QString::arg in Qt?

Tags: qt

QString documentation in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg says

> One advantage of using arg() over
>   sprintf() is that the order of the
>   numbered place markers can change, if
>   the application's strings are
>   translated into other languages, but
>   each arg() will still replace the
>   lowest numbered unreplaced place
>   marker, no matter where it appears.

what is the meaning of this? can anyone please explain with example?

Comment: Another advantage of arg(): sprintf() is [deprecated](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#sprintf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say we start with:

```
QString format("%1: %2 %3);
```

Then call:

```
format.arg("something");
```

Format will now be:

> "something: %1 %2"

...meaning you can build up the string as you go.

Changing the order of the place markers is possible through Qt's translation mechanism, which allows you to say:

```
format = tr("Hi, %1, I hope you are %2");
```

and add it to your translation table and have the parameters in a different order for different languages.

Answer (score 6):

```
int day = 1;
int month = 12;
int year = 2010;
QString dateString = QString(tr("date is %1/%2/%3")).arg(month).arg(day).arg(year);
// dateString == "date is 12/1/2010";
```

With German translation "Das Datum ist: %2.%1.%3": dateString = "Das Datum ist: 1.12.2010"

Comment: Actually that outer `QString(...)` on the RHS is totally redundant...

Answer (score 4):

**A thing to add to sje397 answer:**

When internationalizing your application you can have a string like that:

```
QString formatInAnOtherLanguage("%3 %1 %2");
```

So when calling

```
formatInAnOtherLanguage.arg("something");
```

formatInAnOtherLanguage will be

```
"%3 something %2"
```

That's the main advantage of the arg function over the sprintf function