# How do I insert a variable result into a string in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I just started learning C++ in Qt and I was wondering how can I put a variables result in a string? I'm trying to use this for a simple application where someone puts their name in a text field then presses a button and it displays there name in a sentence. I know in objective-c it would be like,

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormatting:@"Hello, %@", [nameField stringValue]];
[nameField setStringValue:name];
```

How would I go about doing something like this with C++? Thanks for the help

Comment: BTW...if your project is really committed to Qt, there are several good reasons to use the `QString` class instead of `std::string`...one of which is "implicit sharing".  For some perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618798/why-is-there-a-different-string-class-in-every-c-platform-out-there

Comment: "Implicit sharing" is nice when you have limited memory and one CPU core, but slows down multi-threaded programs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don´t mention what type your string is. If you are using the standard library then it would be something along the lines of

```
std::string name = "Hello, " + nameField;
```

That works for concatenating strings, if you want to insert other complex types you can use a stringstream like this:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "Hello, " << nameField;
stream << ", here is an int " << 7;

std::string text = stream.str();
```

Qt probably has its own string types, which should work in a similar fashion.

Comment: There we go! Thanks for the help, I'm supprised its that simple.

Comment: @Natatos: That's not very simple, in my mind, because you need to introduce another variable for the `ostringstream` to create your string.

Comment: @KenBloom: Well, you can always do it with a temporary, like `( std::ostringstream() << "Hello, " << nameField << ", here is an int " << 7 ).str();` but I try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @K-ballo It is not that easy because as soon as you use <<, the stream is upcasted to `std::ostream &` which has no `str()` function, it might work if you are already using C++0x, with an updated STL, but for now, you have to `static_cast` it explicitly to `ostringstream` before calling str.

Comment: See this post for the correct code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303562/c-format-macro-inline-ostringstream

Answer (score 8):

I assume we're talking about Qt's `QString` class here. In this case, you can use the `arg` method:

```
 int     i;           // current file's number
 long    total;       // number of files to process
 QString fileName;    // current file's name

 QString status = QString("Processing file %1 of %2: %3")
                 .arg(i).arg(total).arg(fileName);
```

See the [QString documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#arg) for more details about the many overloads of the `arg` method.

Comment: I suggest a single multi-arg arg(): ...").arg( i, total, fileName ). More robust, in case i or total happen to contain e.g. "%1". And probably also faster.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: There isn't an overload to `arg()` that can handle both `int`s and `QString`s.

Comment: Ken: Right, you have to wrap the int in QString::number() then.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/stringstream/) but I'm not 100% sure how that fits into your NSString case...

```
stringstream ss (stringstream::in);
ss << "hello my name is " << nameField;
```

I think [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html) has some nifty helpers that might do the same thing...

```
QString hello("hello ");
QString message =  hello % nameField;
```

Comment: `QString` has on `operator%` defined AFAICT (see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html)

Comment: See section called More Efficient String Construction in my link

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QString::sprintf`. I haven't found a good example of it's use yet, though. (If someone else finds one, feel free to edit it in to this answer).

You might be interested in seeing information about [the difference between `QString::sprintf` and `QString::arg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322836/what-is-the-difference-between-qstringsprintf-and-qstringarg-in-qt).